# MVC 4 Web API How to prepare JSON body for Request

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have a function that will expose to the RestAPI. I need to pass in a JSON string to be a defined class. I use the following class for JSON format:

```
public class Registrant : Guest
{
    public int RegistrantID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following function in my controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Create(string id, [FromBody]Registrant registrant)
```

However When I pass in the JSON string the same structure, it could not deserialize correctly.

Is there anything wrong with it?

PS: my JSON string in request body:

```
{ 
    "RegistrantID":"0",
    "Email": "abc@abc.com",
    "Phone": "123456789",
    "EventID": "8",
    "IsPrimary": "true",
    "CustomerId": "12345678",
    "FirstName": "abc",
    "LastName": "def"
}
```

---

Update:
The problem is resolved by choosing Content-Type as Application/Json
Also, I took out the quotes on int and bool params it works fine.
Finally the api call look like this in project:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Create([FromUri]string id, [FromBody]Registrant registrant)
```

Comment: Try taking out the quotes for the int/bool types.  I am also assuming your mapping is correct, and there is an id included in the query.

Comment: It is resolved by choose Content-Type: application/JSON. Also Your comment is right. I took out the quotes and it works.